# Not all data coming back from mysql query

Tags: mysql

Lets say that I create 3 tables as follows...

```
create table `users` (`username` varchar(20), `other_non_relevant_field` varchar(20) );
insert into `users` values
("Bob","blah blah blah"),
("Steve","blah blah blah"),
("Sue","blah blah blah"),
("Adam","blah blah blah");


create table `table_1` (`username` varchar(20), `field_abc` varchar(20), `field_def` varchar(20), `other_non_relevant_field` varchar(20) );
insert into `table_1` values
("Steve","blue","brown","blah blah blah"),
("Sue","yellow","brown","blah blah blah"),
("Sue","pink","brown","blah blah blah"),
("Adam","green","brown","blah blah blah");


create table `table_2` (`username` varchar(20), `field_ghi` varchar(20), `field_jkl` varchar(20), `other_non_relevant_field` varchar(20) );
insert into `table_2` values
("Bob","spoon","fork","blah blah blah"),
("Bob","knife","spork","blah blah blah"),
("Steve","spoon","knife","blah blah blah"),
("Sue","spoon","fork","blah blah blah"),
("Sue","knife","spork","blah blah blah"),
("Adam","fork","knife","blah blah blah");
```

and then I run this query...

```
SELECT users.username,
    table_1.field_abc, table_1.field_def,
    table_2.field_ghi, table_2.field_jkl
FROM users
JOIN table_1 ON table_1.username = users.username
JOIN table_2 ON table_2.username = users.username
WHERE
    table_1.field_abc REGEXP "(spork|pink)" OR
    table_1.field_def REGEXP "(spork|pink)" OR
    table_2.field_ghi REGEXP "(spork|pink)" OR
    table_2.field_jkl REGEXP "(spork|pink)"
ORDER BY
(
    ( CASE WHEN table_1.field_abc LIKE "%spork%" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
    ( CASE WHEN table_1.field_abc LIKE "%pink%" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
    ( CASE WHEN table_1.field_def LIKE "%spork%" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
    ( CASE WHEN table_1.field_def LIKE "%pink%" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
    ( CASE WHEN table_2.field_ghi LIKE "%spork%" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
    ( CASE WHEN table_2.field_ghi LIKE "%pink%" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
    ( CASE WHEN table_2.field_jkl LIKE "%spork%" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
    ( CASE WHEN table_2.field_jkl LIKE "%pink%" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
)DESC;
```

Why does it not return Bob's entry that has "spork" in it?
You can see this query in action at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cbbda/5

It goes without saying that this is not my actual code but it is similar enough and has the same issue that I'll be able to figure out where my problem is.

Comment: probably need to change your JOIN type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the default `JOIN` is `INNER`, the query is not returning results for which a table returns `NULL`. Using `LEFT JOIN` returns the "Bob" row, `NULL` values included.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cbbda/7/0

Here is a visual representation of various JOIN types:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

```
SELECT users.username,
  table_1.field_abc, table_1.field_def,
  table_2.field_ghi, table_2.field_jkl
FROM users
LEFT JOIN table_1 ON table_1.username = users.username
LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_2.username = users.username
WHERE
  table_1.field_abc REGEXP "(spork|pink)" OR
  table_1.field_def REGEXP "(spork|pink)" OR
  table_2.field_ghi REGEXP "(spork|pink)" OR
  table_2.field_jkl REGEXP "(spork|pink)"
ORDER BY
(
  ( CASE WHEN table_1.field_abc LIKE "%spork%" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
  ( CASE WHEN table_1.field_abc LIKE "%pink%" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
  ( CASE WHEN table_1.field_def LIKE "%spork%" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
  ( CASE WHEN table_1.field_def LIKE "%pink%" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
  ( CASE WHEN table_2.field_ghi LIKE "%spork%" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
  ( CASE WHEN table_2.field_ghi LIKE "%pink%" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
  ( CASE WHEN table_2.field_jkl LIKE "%spork%" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
  ( CASE WHEN table_2.field_jkl LIKE "%pink%" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
)DESC;
```

Comment: Ok... I get that it is not `JOIN` because that defaults to `INNER JOIN` but I am still reading and trying to wrap my head around why the correct answer is `LEFT JOIN` and not `OUTER JOIN`

Comment: Just for kicks I tried changing it to "yellow" and "spork" as seen at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cbbda/10 and have Sue returned 3 times. It must be due to how the join is working but there are only 2 actual records that match "yellow" or "spork" for Sue. In my actual code I will be adding `GROUP BY users.username` so I will only actually get one record returned for each user but I am just curious if I still have something wrong or not. Also will the extra results affect performance in anyway on a large database?

Answer (score 2):

Because Bob is not present in table_1 elements, and the JOIN discards rows that don't have matching rows in all joined tables.

In order to achieve what you want, change JOIN by LEFT JOIN in the two appearances. This way you will have all 'Users' elements joined with table_1 and table_2 elements that match or null if no match is found.