# mysql query taking too long

Tags: mysql

I am new to advanced queries so I likely have something conceptually wrong because when the database has over 1 million records I get this response rom my query...

`ERROR 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

Yes! It actually takes so long that it pukes before it finishes.

My query is this...

```
SELECT users.username,
    table_1.field_abc, table_1.field_def,
    table_2.field_ghi, table_2.field_jkl
FROM users
LEFT JOIN table_1 ON table_1.username = users.username
LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_2.username = users.username
WHERE
    table_1.field_abc REGEXP "(spork|yellow)" OR
    table_1.field_def REGEXP "(spork|yellow)" OR
    table_2.field_ghi REGEXP "(spork|yellow)" OR
    table_2.field_jkl REGEXP "(spork|yellow)"
GROUP BY users.username
ORDER BY
(
    ( CASE WHEN table_1.field_abc LIKE "%spork%" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
    ( CASE WHEN table_1.field_abc LIKE "%yellow%" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
    ( CASE WHEN table_1.field_def LIKE "%spork%" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
    ( CASE WHEN table_1.field_def LIKE "%yellow%" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
    ( CASE WHEN table_2.field_ghi LIKE "%spork%" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
    ( CASE WHEN table_2.field_ghi LIKE "%yellow%" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
    ( CASE WHEN table_2.field_jkl LIKE "%spork%" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
    ( CASE WHEN table_2.field_jkl LIKE "%yellow%" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
)DESC;
```

I posted a sample dataset (with only a few records) at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cbbda/28

The sample at sqlfiddle runs quick because there are only a few records but I tried duplicating records on my own server and the query ran quick with only a few records and extremely slow after I added a million records.

Is there any possible way to get my results quick?

Comment: This looks like a fun query...heh... do you have indexes on your comparison columns?

Comment: +1 for actually taking time to indent your sql nicely

Comment: @Loren Please forgive me... I am new... Indexes?

Comment: New?? this is an amazing query for someone who is new... anyways - maybe this can help some in regards to indexes: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html

Comment: Indexes likely wont help the comparison much since its like with % to start the value...

Comment: Yes... new.  I have learned the power of StackOverflow and Google research and managed to get it to work but obviously not well enough.

Comment: In your fiddle, `spork` and `yellow` are the entire value of the fields. In the real data, can they be in the middle of the string?

Comment: How's the performance if you leave out the `ORDER BY`? If that `REGEXP` part performs ok, and you don't get an absurd number of results back, you may be able to retrieve them all unsorted, then sort them in memory in your application.

Comment: How many rows are typically returned as a result? Both answers have commented on the ORDER BY clause, but that's only an issue if there are many rows returned.

Comment: @Barmar Good point - I didn't think about that, so removing the `ORDER BY` wouldn't really help, at least not dramatically.

Comment: @Barmar Yes... The sample data is just bogus. My real data is actually partial data components which as a whole create a user resume. The user is asked for different bits of info which is stored in different tables. I am trying to create a search that checks all tables.

Comment: It would probably be better to store this data in `text` fields and use mysql's full-text searching, rather than regexp.

Comment: @Barmar full-text searching.... something else for me to Google I guess

Comment: @Barmar you are a genius... full-text searching did the trick... See my answer - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well folks... With your help we have a solution... See...  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fcfbd/5
BUT I DO STILL HAVE A QUESTION...

I altered the table to add the indexes...

```
ALTER TABLE  `users` ADD FULLTEXT ( `username` );
ALTER TABLE  `table_1` ADD FULLTEXT ( `field_abc`,`field_def` );
ALTER TABLE  `table_2` ADD FULLTEXT ( `field_ghi`,`field_jkl` );
```

I then took the advice of @Barmar and changed the code to this...

```
SELECT users.username,
    table_1.field_abc, table_1.field_def,
    table_2.field_ghi, table_2.field_jkl
FROM users
LEFT JOIN table_1 ON table_1.username = users.username
LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_2.username = users.username
WHERE
    MATCH(table_1.field_abc,table_1.field_def,table_2.field_ghi,table_2.field_jkl)
    AGAINST ("spork yellow" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
GROUP BY users.username
ORDER BY
(
    ( CASE WHEN MATCH(table_1.field_abc) AGAINST ("spork" IN BOOLEAN MODE) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
    ( CASE WHEN MATCH(table_1.field_abc) AGAINST ("yellow" IN BOOLEAN MODE) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +

    ( CASE WHEN MATCH(table_1.field_def) AGAINST ("spork" IN BOOLEAN MODE) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
    ( CASE WHEN MATCH(table_1.field_def) AGAINST ("yellow" IN BOOLEAN MODE) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +

    ( CASE WHEN MATCH(table_2.field_ghi) AGAINST ("spork" IN BOOLEAN MODE) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
    ( CASE WHEN MATCH(table_2.field_ghi) AGAINST ("yellow" IN BOOLEAN MODE) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +

    ( CASE WHEN MATCH(table_2.field_ghi) AGAINST ("spork" IN BOOLEAN MODE) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
    ( CASE WHEN MATCH(table_2.field_ghi) AGAINST ("yellow" IN BOOLEAN MODE) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
)DESC;
```

With over 1,000,000 records in my real database, I got my result in 6.5027 seconds. That is A LOT better than... well, taking so long that it puked!

My only question now is... Why does it only work with IN BOOLEAN MODE and not the other 2 options mentioned at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match or http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html?

Comment: Maybe because of this: _In addition, words that are present in 50% or more of the rows are considered common and do not match._

Comment: I don't think you need a full-text index on the `username` column.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry for the confusion... By not working, I didn't mean that I don't get any results, I meant that I get a syntax error. Apparently it is an invalid query without the `IN BOOLEAN MODE`. I can't seem to get the other modes to work.

Comment: That seems wrong, since the documentation specifically says that natural language mode is the default if no modifier is given. How can that be right if it's a syntax error. Did you have parentheses around the search string? It looks like they're required even without a modifier.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so - with this table as-is, I doubt you'll make that run fast with all of those `LIKE`s on them. Those have to run a ridiculous number of times.

If those values are fixed, then you can add new columns to the table called `abc_like_yellow` and `abc_like_spork`, etc., and populate those values one time, then you can easily query off of that column.

But if you're trying to do this dynamically, you might be out of luck.

Comment: Not fixed data.... Just sample bogus data. Actual data is different in each record.

Comment: I think he means fixed in the query -- are you always looking for `spork` and `yellow`, so you could add boolean columns for those?

Answer (score 0):

Since we're joining on `username` it is likely that an index on this column will speed things up.

Also, are you able to use an inner join as opposed to a left join? This can also speed up the query to quite a large extent.

And finally, if necessary, the ordering can be done in memory as opposed to asking the database to do it (ie order the result set after it is returned).

Comment: I can't use INNER JOIN... I tried... See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958386/not-all-data-coming-back-from-mysql-query

Answer (score 0):

I was using my first solution but found that it gave some false positives that I could not figure out so I came up with this...

```
(SELECT username, MATCH(field_abc,field_def) AGAINST ("spork yellow" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score FROM table_1 HAVING score>0)
UNION ALL
(SELECT username, MATCH(field_ghi,field_jkl) AGAINST ("spork yellow" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score FROM table_2 HAVING score >0)
```

Since each record was returned separately and I can't use `GROUP BY` I added this PHP code after my query finished:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) )
{
    if( in_array($row['username'],$usernames) )
    {
        $usernames_count[$row['username']] += $row['score'];
    }
    else
    {
        array_push($usernames,$row['username']);
        $usernames_count[$row['username']]=$row['score'];
    }
}
arsort($usernames_count); // Sort the results high->low

foreach($usernames_count as $key=>$value)
{
    echo "Username: ".$key." had a score of ".$value." in the search results<br/>";
}
```

It now seems so simple compared to the other attempts I made.

Answer (score 0):

When your server has to scan through millions of entries, it simply may not be powerful enough to process the query quickly.

In general, to improve the speed of your website, you could try [CloudFlare](http://cloudflare.com)

If you are specifically trying to speed up your SQL, [Google Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/) may be able to help. Google's powerful servers are designed to scan through billions of SQL entries, for example when a Google search is performed.

As long as there are no errors being returned, the above two services will help to dramatically speed up your query time.

I hope I could help!

```
VCNinc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to SQL Server, highlight your complete query in SQL server, and click  + L

This will show the query execution plan. Optimize the query based on these results;

if for example you see table scans then an index may assist. 
 Write queries that do not use the term distinct.
 Do not order results if the order is unimportant.

In your sample the complicated last set of order-by is very expensive.

Rather follow these steps:
 Pull the core information into a temporary table, with 9 extra columns (type int, intially set to 0) 
 after populating the core data, update each of the 8 columns based on the 0 or 1 criteria
 update the last column as the sum of the other 8 columns
 retrieve info from the table , with only a single "order-by" based on column 9.

In my experience this approach only takes 20% of the time compared to doing the order-by in-house.